# Pandas select data from row where column names vary

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple tables, which i built from txt files. They have different number of columns with different names. Columns I'm most interested in have names, say "data" or "data7" ... "data0" or "data15" ... "data0".

I need to select rows from these tables with some specific values in "data" columns, say data==1234, but want to display other column info as well, say colA, colB along-with these "data" columns.

**What I have so far**:

result = df.filter(regex='data|colA|colB|colC') to filter out columns i need to see.

**What I need**:

From result dataframe, I need to select entries so that *data* has specific values. Problem is internet tutorials give queries like result[(result.data == abc)]  and it errors out saying "data column not found".

Is there any way to execute query on %data% columns of result dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: To find the value in *any* column, you can use... `any`!

```
>>> df

  col1 col2  data1  data2
0    a    e   1234     12
1    b    f   5678     34
2    c    g   9101   1234
3    d    h   1121     78

>>> df.filter(regex='data1|data2|col1')[df.isin([1234]).any(axis=1)]

  col1  data1  data2
0    a   1234     12
2    c   9101   1234
```

Docs: [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

---

OLD ANSWER

Just match the column to your value:

```
>>> df

  col1 col2  data1  data2
0    a    e   1234     12
1    b    f   5678     34
2    c    g   9101     56
3    d    h   1234     78

>>> df.filter(regex='data1|data2|col1')[df['data1'] == 1234]

  col1  data1  data2
0    a   1234     12
3    d   1234     78
```

Comment: But the match can be in either data1 or data2 or so on, not necessarily data1, and I have no way to telling which one. Could be any

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler I edited with the answer that solves your problem given the extra details.